# UITextFieldViewModeAlways cause crash of my app

Tags: ios

is happened a strange bug. In my app I have a login screen with 2 textfield, username and password.
For more legibility i would create a left space padding. Ok, I have been writed:

```
UIView *spacerViewuser = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
UIView *spacerViewpwd = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];

[usertextfield setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
[usertextfield setLeftView:spacerViewuser];
[pwdtextfield setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
[pwdtextfield setLeftView:spacerViewpwd];
```

But this causes a crash of my app. The error is:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue
>   waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main
>   thread.'

Any ideas?

Comment: The error message is telling you pretty precisely what is wrong. You're trying to update/change the UI via some other thread but you can only update UI via the main thread. See :https://stackoverflow.com/a/30954316/2127691

Comment: @MarcoNeves `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` does not work